# Disable event listeners with synchronized methods

Tags: java, swing

My GUI application has methods that [re-]load data for `JTable` instances (like eg `File->New`, `File->Open` menu items). When items are being loaded or emptied, the event listeners are active and start handling objects in an undefined state, hence raising exceptions and conflicting with the loading operation.

I want to stop the listeners during loading operations. So I thought one solution would be making both the loading and the listener methods `synchronized`.

What I have is a few instances of `JTable`, and the listener is a `TableModelListener`. So, for example, when `File->New` is clicked, it fires this method:

```
private synchronized void newFileClicked() { 
    // empty all tables in the application
}
```

And in the conflicting listener:

```
class MyModelListener implements TableModelListener {
    @Override public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent tme) {
        synchronized (this) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

But still, when the `newFileClicked` method is called, simultaneous output from this and the `tableChanged` methods occur.

Is my understanding of `synchronized` wrong? Or is this implementation not correct?

May be both ?=/

---

edit: corrected implementation after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60113638/5069105) answer also has the same symptom

```
Object lock = new Object();

private void newFileClicked() { 
    synchronized (lock) {
        // empty all tables in the application
    }
}

class MyModelListener implements TableModelListener {
    @Override public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent tme) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
// Still does not work ! =/
```

Answer (score 1):

System level events (like MouseEvents or KeyEvents) are added to the end of the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) and are processed sequentially.

Swing level events (like the TableModelEvent) are processed at the time the event is generated. That is the event is NOT added to the EDT.

> I want to stop the listeners during loading operations.

You need to do something like:

1. remove the listeners
2. load the data
3. restore the listeners

Or you could use a a boolean variable like "loading" and then have each of the listeners check if you are currently "loading" and if so, skip the processing.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of these different methods. My concern is more to understand why `synchronized` doesn't work. Basically you're saying then that `synchronized` methods and blocks will not work in Swing? To ensure synchronization with listeners or threads, another approach like boolean flags must be used?

Comment: What I'm saying is that there is nothing to synchronize because all the code is executing on the EDT, so it already is single threaded. Synchronization is used when you have code executing on multiple threads. If the TableModelEvent was a true system event then it would be added to the end of the EDT to execute AFTER all the data was cleared in your tables, but it is not a true event and the listener code is invoked as soon as the data is cleared from the TableModel.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using `synchronized` on different objects. `synchronized` will only block if a lock is held on exactly the same object.

In fact, Swing is super *thread-hostile*. Restrict usage to the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) - use `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater`. If you need other threads, make sure they don't touch anything Swing. Copy data to and from the EDT on the EDT.

Comment: Good point about this error in my code. To make the correction, I've added a field at the main class, `final private Object lock = new Object()` and passed it into the `synchronized (lock) {}` block in the inner class. Also added a `synchronized (lock) {}` block in the `newFileClicked` method. However the same "unsynchronized" behavior insists to occur after correcting this. =/